# last separator in list not showing

Tags: html, css

I've got a horizontal list as following.

```
 <ul>
 <li>Credits Left : 200 USD</li>
 <li>Items Cold : 58</li>
 <li>System Status : Online</li>
 <li>Sync Details : Updated </li>
 </ul>
```

The Css is as following.

```
  #status ul{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

#status li{
float: left;
list-style: none;
display: block;
padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
color: #dcdcdc;
font-size: 14px;
font-family:MyriadProReg;
background: url(../images/header_li_bg.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}
```

But I the last element is not showing the separator image. how can I fix this. The image will explain the issue.

[image: Result of my CSS]

Comment: you are positioning the image at the left of each element.
I suggest a solution via borders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not showing the last separator because you're using a background image on the left of the menu items (none on the right). Here is one way you could fix it using pseudo-elements (IE8+) and absolute positioning.

Add these styles:

```
#status li {
    position:relative;
}
#status li:last-child:after {
    display:block;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    background: url(../images/header_li_bg.jpg) no-repeat top left;

    /* width of background image */
    width:5px;
    /* height of background image */
    height:40px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but your answer had one wrong thing! you've defined two width amounts rather than height & width. I edited it and that works very well! thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#status ul{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px;
background: url(../images/header_li_bg.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}

#status li{
float: left;
list-style: none;
display: block;
padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
color: #dcdcdc;
font-size: 14px;
font-family:MyriadProReg;
background: url(../images/header_li_bg.jpg) no-repeat top right;
}
```